# python construct nested dict dynamically

Tags: python

I want to create a nested dict in python dynamically. By saying that:
given

```
tuple1 = ('A','B'), 
tuple2 = ('A','C'), 
dict = {}
```

I'd like to have `dict` like `dict = {'A': {'B':1}}` after adding `tuple1` to `dict`;
then `dict = {'A': {'B' : 1, 'C' : 1}}` after adding `tuple2` to `dict`
That's what I have tried, i find the following code to create nested dict recursively. But I'm not sure how to add node dynamically and also increment its value by 1.

```
def incr_dict(dct, tpl):
   if len(tpl) == 0:
      dct = dct
   else:
      dct = {tpl[-1]:dct}
      return incr_dict(dct, tpl[0:-1])
   return dct

dct = {}
tpl = ('a', 'b', 'c')

dct = incr_dict(dct, tpl)
print(dct)
```

Comment: maplist seems to be a set, how does A become the primary key?

Comment: I think he means `{'A': 'B'}` and `{'A': 'C'}`

Comment: The best way to get anything done in python is by writing code, have you tried doing that?

Comment: @o11c now it's more clear

Comment: Not to me it isn't. I was thinking you might want `collections.Counter`, but I'm just confused.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I tried. I only be able to create nest dict. But I'm not sure how to dynamically add nodes into it. That's why I come SO to ask for help.

Comment: I think @LegoStormtroopr's point is that it's a lot easier for us to help you if you show us what you've already tried, ad explain how the result from that is different than what you desire.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I made the correction. please take a look.

Comment: @o11c I add more explanation. I should be more clear now.

Comment: Seems kind of like two different questions in one, now that you've shared your code, since I don't understand the relationship between `tuple1 / tuple2` in the first code block, and `tpl` in the second.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the below code, you will have a dict `d` which is `{'A': {'B': 1, 'C': 1}}`; note that the outermost loop isn't strictly necessary, but it saved me some typing in this instance.

```
tuple1 = ('A','B')
tuple2 = ('A','C')
d = {}
for l in [list(tuple1), list(tuple2)]:
    for k in l:
        v = l.pop()
        if (d.has_key(k)):
            if (d[k].has_key(v)):
                d[k][v] = d[k][v]+1
            else:
                d[k][v] = 1
        else:
            d[k] = {}
            d[k][v] = 1
```